how to combine 2 API response in flutter?
i want to combine 2 api result in infinite scroll pagination, the first api (wi) is successfully displayed in the UI, but the second api (exprenprod) displayed only data from page 1, how to fetch all page from second api based value from first api?
below is  my getWi to combine and display all api results :
Future<void> getWi(int page, int limit) async {
    try {
      final dataWi = await _wiRepository.fetchWi(page, limit, _searchQuery);
      await _kodeProyekController.fetchAndMatchProyekDetails(dataWi);
      await _expRenprodController.fetchExpRenprod(dataWi, page, limit);
      final isLastPage = dataWi.length < _limit;
      if (isLastPage) {
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(dataWi);
      } else {
        _pagingController.appendPage(dataWi, page + 1);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      _pagingController.error = 'Error : $e';
    }
  }

i've try to add page and limit to the url, but only page 1 has been fetched
below my controller to fetch data
class ExpRenprodController extends GetxController {
  final ExpRenprodRepository _expRenprodRepository = ExpRenprodRepository();
  var sttpRenprod = <String?, ExpRenprod>{}.obs;

  Future fetchExpRenprod(List<Wi> allWi, int page, int limit) async {
    try {
      List<ExpRenprod> expRenprodResponse =
          await _expRenprodRepository.fetchExpRenprod(page, limit);

      for (Wi wi in allWi) {
        ExpRenprod? matchedExpRenprod = expRenprodResponse.firstWhereOrNull(
          (expRenprod) => expRenprod.cp == wi.noCtplan,
        );

        if (matchedExpRenprod != null) {
          sttpRenprod[wi.noCtplan] = matchedExpRenprod;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

